# Linking shared library libdvbv5, undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I am using the libdvbv5 library however I am having issues getting my program to compile.

I have the headers in /usr/local/include and there is libdvbv5.so in /usr/local/lib.

The code is extremely simple:

```
#include "libdvbv5/dvb-dev.h"

void doSatTest() {
    struct dvb_device *dvb;
    struct dvb_dev_list *dvb_dev;

    dvb = dvb_dev_alloc();
}
```

The eclipse indexer is satisfied that the function "dvb_dev_alloc" exists in the header file "dvb-dev.h" and the file compiles but fails on link

I have stopped using the eclipse builder so i can simplify the build command and pinpoint what is happening.

I try to compile and link using the following command:

```
g++ sat_test.cpp -ldvbv5
```

However it fails with:

```
sat_test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `dvb_dev_alloc()'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And that is the *only* message you get? On many Linux systems `/usr/local` is not part of the standard include or library search paths.

Comment: Yes the only message, the full message is: `/tmp/cc3BD0pW.o: In function "doSatTest()":
sat_test.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to "dvb_dev_alloc()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the the `libdvbv5/dvb-dev.h` does not provide a proper `C++` prototype, and you are including it into a `.cpp` file.

The fix is to do this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "libdvbv5/dvb-dev.h"
}
... rest as before.
```

With above fix, your program will link fine.

A more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/50617).